# Introjucer/Visual Studio 2013 object file clashes

Tags: juce

I've got two files in my build named State.cpp. When I generate the VS project with the Introjucer and try to compile, both of those files clash to the same object file and I get the warning:

> Warning 1 warning MSB8027: Two or more files with the name of
>   State.cpp will produce outputs to the same location. This can lead to
>   an incorrect build result.  The files involved are
>   ......\audio\State.cpp, ......\sg\State.cpp.

and then various link errors.

I can correct this easily enough within VS by modifying the Object File Name property on the VS project. However, when I regenerate the project with the Introjucer, that setting gets blown away.

Is there a setting I can use in the Inrojucer's config pages to prevent the clashes?

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this one down...

There isn't.  Rename the file for now.

We discussed this on the forum.  I think Jules is up for making a change to the Introjucer to fix this - but it hasn't been done yet.

http://www.juce.com/forum/topic/msvc-build-consistency

http://www.juce.com/forum/topic/introjucer/visual-studio-2013-object-file-clashes